# Windows Forms DataGridView control have different control types in the same column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to do the following in a DataGridView:

In the same column I want to change the control type of each row between DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

(this is because sometimes I want to display a drop down list and other times I just want the user to enter a freehand value).

Thanks,

P.S. I am using C#

Comment: Very good question. It is just a matter of time until one faces this issue when using the DataGridView class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own class inherited from DataGridViewCell, and override the adequate virtual members (InitializeEditingControls, EditType, maybe a few others). You can then create a DataGridViewColumn with an instance of this class as the cell template

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like the right track. Unfortunately I am newish to this and I cannot get the cells to appear no matter what I do. I have overriden EditType as suggested. If I inherit from say 'DataGridViewTextBoxCell' then i can see the cell, inheriting from 'DataGridViewCell' and overriding EditType to return typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) gives me a blank cell - I can see the column though. I am sure there is something obvious I have missed.

Comment: It just seems that the view mode control is not showing or has a width if zero? I can tab to the control, hit F2 and type a value. When I exit I can't see it, when I return to edit mode it is still there.

Comment: I think you also need to override PositionEditingPanel and PositionEditingControl. But I never did it myself, so I can only guess... You should use Reflector to have a look at the code for standard DataGridViewCells, it will probably show you what you need to do

Comment: -1 -- I'd love to know if this helped, and what the solution looks like. Because: This answer is just a brief description of "How to create a custom column". What would InitializeEditingControl for example look like? You'd have to execute either TextBoxCell's or ComboBoxCell's version of the method -- but since your custom cell can only inherit from one of them, you'd have to duplicate the code from the other class. And I think it would be infeasable to create two delegates in the custom cell since the would not be linked correctly to the cell/column.

Comment: @TheBlastOne, well, the answer was accepted, so I guess it wasn't so bad as to deserve a downvote...

Comment: @Thomas I disagree. If that would be true, one could just make SO auto-accept the answer with the most votes. The guy asking the questions decides what is accepted. The guys reviewing the answers communicate if they agree or not. Since the answer does not help (in my opinion), it might get downvoted. If it has been accepted or not is not an indicator for usefullness (except for the user who accepted it, of course). Plus: I'll re-upvote as soon as I see inhowfar that helped, and what the solution looks like. "Create a custom column and override EditType etc." opens just those questions.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently had a similar usecase, and ended up writing something like the below code:

Write a custom Cell and Column class, and override the EditType and InitializeEditingControl methods on the cell, to return different controls as appropriate (here I'm just databinding to a list of a custom class with .useCombo field indicating what control to use):

```
// Define a column that will create an appropriate type of edit control as needed.
public class OptionalDropdownColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public OptionalDropdownColumn()
        : base(new PropertyCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a PropertyCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(PropertyCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a PropertyCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

// And the corresponding Cell type
public class OptionalDropdownCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public OptionalDropdownCell()
        : base()
    {           
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);

        DataItem dataItem = (DataItem) this.OwningRow.DataBoundItem;
        if (dataItem.useCombo)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl ctl = (DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)DataGridView.EditingControl;
            ctl.DataSource = dataItem.allowedItems;
            ctl.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl ctl = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)DataGridView.EditingControl;
            ctl.Text = this.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            DataItem dataItem = (DataItem)this.OwningRow.DataBoundItem;
            if (dataItem.useCombo)
            {
                return typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl);
            }
            else
            {
                return typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add a column to your DataGridView of this type, and the correct edit control should be used.

Comment: +1, this looks quite useful and clean to me. The cool thing about this that it just signals the required edit control class "just in time" in the EditType getter, lets the Grid do the hard work, and use the so-created edit control by referencing DataGridView.EditingControl.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template column with both controls in, hide the one you don't want, and bind the other to the datasource in code.