# How do I make my own DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

What I'm trying to do is making

- A DataGridViewDropdownColumn that displays different items in the
  dropdown list for each cell.
- A DataGridViewHybridColumn that
  displays either a TextBox or a ComboBox for each cell.

I read [this](http://www.codemag.com/article/0707061) toturial and made my own DataGridViewBarColumn, but I don't have the slightest clue how I should implement something like this.

Performance doesn't  matter even though there can be upwards of 100K rows in a DataGridView, I'll take care of optimizations later.

I think they're done the same way, so I'm asking them in one question

Comment: I know there is http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewComboBoxCell.cs which has black magic like internal override void CacheEditingControl(). Has anyone done anything clean in less than 4k lines of spaghetti with a usable license?

Comment: I believe this Q&A might be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986233/windows-forms-datagridview-control-have-different-control-types-in-the-same-colu You could potentially use that as a starting point for your custom DataGridViewHybridColumn as it should let you choose the cell type by cell rather than by column.

Comment: @Calcolat I'm doing what is said there already, it's currently near 10K lines of code because mono and .net both used internal and internal protected methods in their implementations, So I had to re-implement a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

What I can give you is a starting point to achieve it:

First, Prepare your binding and create your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

```
private List<string> list = new List<string>();

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        // Data source for you dropdown list
        list.Add("First Option");
        list.Add("Second Option");
        list.Add("Third Option");

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValidating);
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
        dataGridView1.DataError += dataGridView1_DataError;

        // Formatting your ComboBox
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        comboColumn.HeaderText = "Hybrid Data Grid Column";
        comboColumn.DataPropertyName = "Tag";
        //comboColumn.DataSource = list;        

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboColumn);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

}
```

Second, Attached an event for editing once you type:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        if (combo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!combo.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
        {
            // Add the text you type into you bound list and refresh binding
            list.Add(e.FormattedValue.ToString());
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.OwningColumn as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            col.Items.Clear();
            col.Items.AddRange(list);
        }

        // Display what you type
        ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value = e.FormattedValue;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboControl = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (comboControl != null)
        {
            if (comboControl.DropDownStyle != ComboBoxStyle.DropDown)
            {
                comboControl.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
            //Update Items if list has changed (assumes items can't be deleted)
            if (comboControl.Items.Count != list.Count)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.OwningColumn as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                col.Items.Clear();
                col.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
                //Note: current cell's items don't appear to be refreshed by the lines above
                comboControl.Items.Clear();
                comboControl.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample Output:

[image]

**Note :** Since we are adding text input in our bound list it might happen that once you click to dropdown option you will see the additional input. So, I will leave it to you to polish it up.

Comment: Thank you for so much effort for helping me, unfortunately that's really not what I'm asking for. With this method I can't provide the user with a "TextBox" to write text in. Only some of the cells need to be comboboxes. The exact problem with this method is that DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs.Control is a read-only property. I think If I can solve that or find a way around it the problem is solved.

Comment: Why TextBox if you can allow text input in typable combobox?

Comment: because there are few combo boxes and 100k different prices for different items that the user shouldn't get confused with and I may need to add 2 other custom user controls later for a similar situation. It would really make my life easier if I could just choose the cell type with an event like CellValueNeeded.