# visual net. datagriview

Tags: vb.net

In datagridview it will be possible every time I go down a column in the cell, specify the type of object I want. Example in row one I want combobox, in second row I need textbox, in third row check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986233/windows-forms-datagridview-control-have-different-control-types-in-the-same-colu is how it's done on C#, shouldn't be too hard to adapt with https://converter.telerik.com/ or https://icsharpcode.github.io/CodeConverter/

Answer (score 0):

Each column type has a default cell type but you can put any cell you want in any column. You can simply create a cell and place it by indexing the grid, e.g.

```vb
myDataGridView(columnIndex, rowIndex) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

You should choose the column type based on the most common cell type and then create just the cells that need a different type.

Comment: Always `myDataGridView(columnIndex, rowIndex).Dispose()` first.